# Custom block fails if I use a __construct with injections

Tags: magento2, di

This is my (updated) code:

```
<?php

namespace MS\RealReviews\Block;

/**
 * Entity rating block
 *
 */

class Review extends \Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView
{

    protected $customer_id;

    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
    protected $orders;

public function __construct(    
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
    \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    parent::__construct(
         $context, 
         $urlEncoder,
         $jsonEncoder,
         $string,
         $productHelper,
         $productTypeConfig,
         $localeFormat,
         $customerSession,
         $productRepository,
         $priceCurrency,
         $collectionFactory,
         $data
    );
}


    public function getOrders() {

        if (!$this->orders):
            $this->orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect(
                '*'
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'customer_id',
                $this->_getCustomerID()
            )->setOrder(
                'created_at',
                'desc'
            );
        endif;
        return $this->orders;

    }

    protected function _setCustomerID($input){
        $this->customer_id = $input;
    }

    protected function _getCustomerID($input){
        return $this->customer_id;
    }

    public function isRealReview($customer_id){
        $product = $this->getProductId();
        $this->_setCustomerID($customer_id);

        return $product;
    }

}
```

I want to get orders based on the `$customer_id` variable, found in `setCustomerID()`.

When I add `__construct`, I get an error:

```
29-Mar-2017 14:54:24 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 9 passed to MS\RealReviews\Block\Review::__construct() must be an instance of MS\RealReviews\Block\ProductRepositoryInterface, instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor given, called in /home/User/public_html/var/generation/MS/RealReviews/Block/Review/Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in /home/User/public_html/app/code/MS/RealReviews/Block/Review.php
```

If I use this code the Block doesn't work anymore and the output `list.phthml` stays empty.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: if constuct remove from block then its working?

Comment: Yes. Only if I add such constructor it is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to extend **__consturct()** method of **Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView** file.

But above file doesn't have **__consturct()** method and **ListView.php** file extends **Magento\Review\Block\Product\View** file.

So you have to override all class of **__consturct()** method in **View.php** file.

keep below construct() method in your file,

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
    \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $urlEncoder,
        $jsonEncoder,
        $string,
        $productHelper,
        $productTypeConfig,
        $localeFormat,
        $customerSession,
        $productRepository,
        $priceCurrency,
        $collectionFactory,
        $data
    );
}
```

Remove **var/generation** and clear cache.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Module is still not outputting anything. Maybe the getOrders function is malformed?

Comment: which error is generate after used above code?

Comment: There is no error output. :/

Comment: so issue may be possible in your custom function.

Comment: if I remove construct and `getOrders()`, everything works. Also, just removing the constructer make it working again, so the error must be related to the constructor anyhow.

Comment: @Max, I have already comment in above answer, Remove var/generation and check. I think you have issue with not remove var generation folder.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `parent::__construct($context, $data);` but there are no `$context` or `$data` parameters in the constructor.

Your constructor should look like this:

```
public function __construct(    
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
    \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    parent::__construct(
         $context, 
         $urlEncoder,
         $jsonEncoder,
         $string,
         $productHelper,
         $productTypeConfig,
         $localeFormat,
         $customerSession,
         $productRepository,
         $priceCurrency,
         $collectionFactory,
         $data
    );
}
```

In order to call the parent class constructor you need to supply to it all the parameters it expects.

And you are extending the class `\Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView`.
This class does not have a constructor so its parent constructor is called automatically.
`\Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView` extends `Magento\Review\Block\Product\View` that has a constructor with this signature.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
    \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    array $data = []
)
```

SO you need to provide all these parameters when calling your `pareny::__construct`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Module is still not outputting anything. Maybe the `getOrders` function is malformed?

Comment: I've crosschecked it. As soon as I initiate the construct, the Block outputs fails. `error_log` is empty.

Comment: turn on error reporting and you should see the error on the screen.

Comment: Check updated question.